# Unable to print property of returned JSON object from get request

Tags: javascript, json

```
<script>

        var apikey = "someKey";
        var SEid = "0137454dfgsdfgsdfgzxv4435099:pnqp_fvtmsy";
        var query = "Flower";
        var returnedData;

        $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=" + apikey + "&cx=" + SEid + "&q=" + query, function(data){

        console.log(data);
        returnedData = data;
        });

        console.log(returnedData.items[1].formattedUrl);
        </script>
```

I keep getting back the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'items' of undefined

but I can't figure out why the variable returned Data is undefined. I'm not trying to even reference it until *after* I've called the get request.

Please don't flag this question as invalid, I'm really trying to figure this out and have tried for the past 2 days various methods but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: probably shouldn't share an api key

Comment: @brandenM `$.get` makes an asynchronous call  which mean we never know when the response will be back & `js` will not wait for it.So `console.log(returnedData.items[1].formattedUrl);` will be executed instead of waiting for the result.When it is executing `returnedData` is undefined because till now no response has arrived from `$.get` call.
Please check the duplicate.The problem & solution is clearly defined there.Hope it will be useful

Answer (score 1):

The `$.get` is running *asynchronously* - once the script reaches that line, it simply sends out the request, it doesn't wait for the request to complete before continuing.

You can't return a value that's generated asynchronously. You could, however, return a *promise* that, when resolved, resolves with the desired value.

Comment: run `console.log(returnedData.items[1].formattedUrl);` right after you define it, within the curly brackets, and I bet you'll see it.

Comment: Yea but then how do I access it for later and or put it into a global variable?

Comment: @brandenM like I said, return a Promise that resolves with the desired value.

Answer (score 0):

Using `returnedData.toJSON().items` or just `returnedData.get(items).get(0)` directly.